# How to define a class that can convert to any type?

Tags: c++, c++17

I want to make a class which can convert to any type/class.

```cpp
struct any{
  template<typename T>
  operator T(){
    return T();
  }
};
```

```cpp
struct S{};
void f(const S&){}
f(any());  //ok
```

```cpp
//but if no default constructor  will make error
struct S{
  S()=delete;
};
void f(const S&){}
f(any());  //error
```

How can I solve this problem to make a class which can convert to any type/class?

Comment: Ok, this is sounding like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: In what way is a default object of an arbitrary type a *conversion* of anything?

Answer (score 2):

> How can i solve this problem to make a class which can convert to any type/class?

There is no way to solve this problem in general because it is not possible to convert into a non constructible type.

Comment: Technically, you can convert to a reference to such a type ... but that does not help much.